# How to inject MessagesApi outside a controller?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.5

I have a simple class service and it is being injected beautifully on my application. However, I am trying to inject the `messages api` to read a few keys on my message files but I am getting the same error:

> 1) Could not find a suitable constructor in play.i18n.Messages.
>   Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with
>   @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private. at
>   play.i18n.Messages.class(Messages.java:61)

```
public class SampleServiceImpl implements SampleService {
  private MessagesApi messages;

  @Inject
  public SampleServiceImpl(MessagesApi messages){
     this.messages = messages;
  }
}

@ImplementedBy(SampleServiceImpl.class)
    public interface SampleService {
}
```

Is the a way to do that by DI?

#### Edit:

I was able to get the value by doing this but it does not look elegant, any options ?

```
messages.get(new Lang(new Locale("en")), "ticket.form.title")
```

Comment: Why does it complain about `Messages` when you are trying to inject `MessagesApi`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of such "non-elegancy" is that language (and `Messages`) depends on the request.

The Default behavior is that Messages detect current language on the base of cookie, available languages and default language.

Someware under the hood: `Messages messages = messagesApi.preferred(request());`

> - Will select a language from the request, based on the languages
>   available, and fallback to the default language if none of the
>   candidates are available.

Fortunately, [there is a special method](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/i18n/MessagesApi.java#L117) that you can use to initialize `Messages` with the language you want:

```
import play.i18n.MessagesApi;
import play.i18n.Messages;
import play.i18n.Lang;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

...

Locale englishLocale = new Locale("en");
Lang englishLang = new Lang(englishLocale);
List<Lang> preferredLangs = Arrays.asList(englishLang);
    
Messages messagesCustom = messagesApi.preferred(preferredLangs);

// the time for elegancy 
messages.at("ticket.form.title");
```

I advise you to create tiny `MessagesApiCustom` service, that will do this few strings of code in the initialization time and then will proxy the `at` method to the `messages.at`, so it will look like:

```
public class SampleServiceImpl implements SampleService {
  private MessagesApiCustom messages;

  @Inject
  public SampleServiceImpl(MessagesApiCustom messages){
     this.messages = messages;
  }

  private void doSomeStuff(){
    Strign message = messages.at("message.key")
  }
}
```

You can go further, and implement language selection based on annotation:

```
 @Named("FR")
 private MessagesApiCustom messages;
```

Of course, if you need the dynamic language selection, then just use the method that is already present in Play.